# « Ni » est-il acceptable dans « peu encombrants ni contraignants » ?

Tags: grammaire, négation, syntaxe

L'utilisation de `ni` dans cette phrase est-elle légitime, sachant que la tournure est affirmative ?

> Un capteur à cet endroit est peu encombrant ni contraignant.

Comment: Ça me fait penser au `ni` dans `Font plus que force ni que rage` chez La Fontaine, où il semble motivé par le sens plutôt que par la grammaire.

Comment: Le problème dans cette forme est que selon notre compréhension moderne l'idée qui se dégage de ce « ni que (la) rage » est assez clairement  « et que la rage non plus » ; cela donne « font plus que la rage non plus », ce qui est du pur non sens. Vu sous le jour de la grammaire moderne, il y a apparemment une erreur dans la grammaire de La Fontaine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Si on suit Grevisse (§1087) *"ni sert à coordonner deux portions négatives"*.

Pas de négation explicite dans "*peu encombrant*" => On ne peut utiliser ni.

On notera tout de même en poursuivant la lecture que le côté négatif du premier membre n'est pas nécessairement explicite. Il cite :

(à-peine/ni) : *"On s'aperçoit à peine que les maîtres flamands aient étudié les Bellini, Giorgione **ni** Titien"*.

(peu/ni chez Camus) : *"Il importe peu que votre critique examine de façon futile certaines démonstrations secondaires ni qu'il pousse l'inconscience..."*

Il suffit donc que dans l'idée de l'auteur *à peine* ou *peu* signifient en fait *pas du tout* pour que... ça marche!

On finira à la recherche du temps perdu... : *"Quelle chance y avait-t-il pour qu'elle se le fût rappelé, ni mon visage."*

Bref...en finale... on peut quand même donc avoir un truc *peu encombrant ni contraignant*, à la condition que tu penses ce truc pas encombrant... du tout.
Maintenant... dans le cadre d'un avis technique...:
j'aurais peine à recommander Camus, Proust ni aCOSwt... ;-)

Comment: Supers exemples ! Oui, j'ai dû abandonner ce ni délicieusement proustien pour un "n'est guère x ni y". Merci !

Answer (score 2):

Ce n'est tout d'abord pas une construction à laquelle on est habitué ; si l'on se réfère à la définition du TLFi,

> NI, conj. de coordination négative. Coordonne des constituants de même nature et de même fonction ou bien des propositions, en corrélation soit avec ne, soit avec d'autres éléments à valeur négative],

on a une confirmation que la construction ne peut pas convenir ; les éléments coordonnés ne le sont ni en corrélation avec « ne » ni avec un élément à valeur négative (« ni » étant l'élément évident de ce type).

Il semble que la seule  possibilité de formuler cette idée complexe avec une économie de mots soit seulement de recourir à la coordination simple;

- Un capteur à cet endroit est peu encombrant et (il n'est) pas contraignant.

Autre possibilité :

> Un capteur à cet endroit n'est ni très encombrant ni contraignant.

Comment: La dernière suggestion est du registre du français parlé. On écrit plutôt: *un capteur à cet endroit n'est ni très encombrant ni contraignant*.

Comment: @jlliagre Vrai, merci !

Answer (score -1):

Non. On aurait pu écrire, en laissant le reste de la phrase intact :

> Un capteur à cet endroit est peu encombrant **ou** contraignant.